# Attempting two level authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory, web-config

Using ASP.NET - Trying to add two-level authentication with forms authentication and windows authentication.

Just following mikes work on `http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/`

The first thing he asks us to do:

```
1. Unlock the <anonymousAuthentication> and <windowsAuthentication> configuration sections before you can use them in web.config:

> %windir%system32inetsrvappcmd unlock config /section:anonymousAuthentication
> %windir%system32inetsrvappcmd unlock config /section:windowsAuthentication
```

I cant seem to find where this is done. Does he mean the web.config file? or edit the machine.config file? in the Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/etc... folder

please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are commands, so you run them at the command prompt. Hit Win R on your keyboard and then enter `cmd` and click OK. This will open a command prompt. Then you enter the first command and press enter, then the second command and press enter.

Perhaps this is a copy/paste error, but you appear to be missing the backslashes between your directory paths. Make sure you include those when you run the command.

Comment: thanks for the help manson...yeah only seeing that now. but thats the way mike has it. does C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config / section:anonymousAuthentication look better? this isnt working says ERROR < message:cannot find SIT object with identifier "sectionanonymousAuthentication".> any idea as to what Im doing wrong? ta

Comment: @John You're probably missing a colon, make sure you type the command exactly as it appears. Also, my name is Mason, not Manson. [Manson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Manson) was someone I'd rather not be associated with.

Comment: Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config /section:anonymousAuthentication is the correct path to use in cmd....thanks for the help 'manson' apologies on the whole identity thing